# Authorization in Amplify GraphQL

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm implementing a project in Amplify and have 3 GraphQL schema types as shown below. It is a multi-tenanted app with different user types.

```
type Seller
@model
@auth (rules: [
   { allow: owner, ownerField: "id", operations: [read, update] },
])
{
   id: ID!
   name: String
   ...
}


type Customer
@model
@auth (rules: [
   { allow: owner, ownerField: "id", operations: [read, update] },
])
{
   id: ID!
   name: String
   ...
}


type Order
@model
@auth (rules: [
   { allow: owner, ownerField: "seller_id", operations: [create, read, update, delete] },
   { allow: owner, ownerField: "customer_id", operations: [read] },
])
{
   id: ID!
   seller_id: ID
   seller: Seller @connection(fields: ["seller_id"])
   customer_id: ID
   customer: Customer @connection(fields: ["customer_id"])
   quantity: Int
   product: String
   ...
}
```

When a user of type Customer is logged in, and calls listOrders, it returns null for the attribute "sellers" presumably because the @auth rules of Seller only allow owners read access. I can fix this by putting a group rules in Seller as follows:

```
type Seller
...
@auth (rules: [
...
   { allow: groups, groups: ["Customer"], operations: [read] },
...
```

However, Customers are now able to query all Sellers (via listSellers or getSellers), which I do not want for them to be able to do.

Is there a way to define authorization so that if customer is authorized on Order, and Order includes the object Seller, then authorization is allowed for that Seller ?

Comment: UPDATE: I tried turning off Seller queries (@model(queries: null)). This ensures that Seller info can only be queries through the Order.seller attribute, but of course has the effect of Sellers not being able to query their own selves.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are going for here but I think you are slightly off with your strategy. What I believe you really are trying to do here is have [Group Authorization](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#static-group-authorization).

Imagine instead that you had Customer and Seller groups. When a Customer registers, they are placed into the Customer group, and when a Seller registers, they are placed into the Seller group. This will allow you to have finer control over groups and their allowed actions. You will probably want to leverage [Dynamic Group Authorization](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#dynamic-group-authorization) for Sellers and Customers, so that a specific Seller can only work with their Customers.

Also, I think you can simplify your custom owners down to just having the [default owner capability that is default with Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#static-group-authorization).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have defined Seller and Customer (and also Admin) Cognito groups along with post confirmation lambda triggers to add users to their respective group at sign up. My aim is -- for security -- to limit who can run listQueries on Sellers. I want only Sellers to query themselves. I want Customers to only query Sellers on which they have placed Orders through the 'seller' attribute of each Order. I do not want Sellers or Customers to query Sellers with whom they may not have any Orders / affiliation.